# Why was “At what point can you you implement crypto algorithms?” migrated to Crypto.SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, cryptography

Why was https://security.stackexchange.com/q/88834/at-what-point-can-you-you-implement-crypto-algorithms migrated to [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)?

From my perspective as a Security.SE user, this question is on-topic. It's about risk management: deciding when you should roll your own crypto implementation vs using someone else's. I could understand that the question could be considered *too broad*, but I don't see how it's off-topic in any way. Cryptography is directly relevant to security, and managing risk is the job of a security professional.

From my perspective as a Crypto.SE user, this question is unanswerable — fitting under both *primarily opinion-based* and *off-topic*. It isn't about cryptography itself, but about deciding how to go about using it, which is off-topic — it fits the close reason “Questions about security policies that may be based on cryptography (as opposed to the design of cryptographic algorithms and protocols) are off-topic here, but may be asked on Security”. Inasmuch as cryptography is concerned, the only Crypto.SE answer is “if you feel like it”.

As [I had written before](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25526/at-what-point-can-you-you-implement-crypto-algorithms#comment58547_25526), I had to [vote to close the question on Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25526/at-what-point-can-you-you-implement-crypto-algorithms#comment58567_25526) once it was migrated. The question is now [undergoing a contested close review](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/review/close/13995). Migrating questions back and forth isn't good experience, and migrating questions to a site where it isn't even answerable is definitely not good.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in chat - the question had a close vote and a flag for migration to Crypto. I saw that it wasn't on topic here as currently worded, as there is nothing in it on risk management, and if anything is an opinion piece on how to decide when you are capable of writing your own crypto. I followed the flag for migration, hoping it would be better served over there.

If you can edit it to make it into a risk management question that is answerable (as opposed to opinon based) then I'd have no objection to it.